# What does the following code segment do?

Tags: c, while-loop, malloc

What does the following code segment do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int num=0;
    while(malloc(1<<10)) ++num;
}
```

Comment: It causes memory leaks.

Comment: You have asked a question that upset the SO glitterati. Please consider reformatting it and re-asking it so it looks like you have a programming problem to solve.

Comment: @nicomp Huh? Same to you buddy..

Comment: @Bak1139 I am helping you. Really. Rewrite your question with an mvce. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is not a guessing game. Please explain the reason why you are contemplating this piece of code and what you expext it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `1<<10` is an expression that can be calculated at compile time, and it equals 1024. So your code is equivalent to

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num=0;
    while(malloc(1024)) ++num;
}
```

So what it does is to allocate chunks of 1024 bytes of memory until it fails to do so. Each time, the value of `num` is increased by one.

Overflowing the variable `num` will cause *undefined behavior* because it is signed. However, since you are not using the variable, it is likely to be optimized away.

Comment: Yep, it assigns memory to num variables until it can do so no more.

Comment: No, the memory just get allocated and is then forgotten. `num` gets incremented once every allocation. Nothing more. But as I said, if you turn on optimizations this code will be optimized to `int main() { while(malloc(1024)); }`

Comment: It does not assign memory to any variables. It merely counts the number of times `malloc` may be called before it returns `NULL`.